# How to hide my IP when using proxies?

Tags: macos, mac, proxy

Why is it so that when I set a HTTP proxy in the system preferences app, but some "my ip" sites still show my ip like in comma separated list in the first place?
For example this one: http://my.ip.lv/
I dont remember having such issues on my Windows machine. What should I do to hide my ip totally and use only the proxy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proxies usually add an [X-Forwarded-For](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) HTTP header that informs the target web-server of the true origin of the request.

There are anonymising proxies available which do not do this - a quick [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=public+anonymous+proxy) will find them.

Comment: The WWW site hyperlinked-to in the question is using that very header.